# Getting weird error when doing npm install in my angular project

Tags: node.js

- node version - 10.15.3
- npm version - 6.9.0
- ng version - 8.0.1

Here is the error message ::

`> npm WARN tarball tarball data for @angular/compiler@8.0.0 (sha512-4rKsVFMNykF83tPL1VE1+j9kZ3cWHUsLOAB/VqmF64EcR/GsbjKog2v23rSso5kqUtPiVq/FWGYllW6qMdxtJA==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for typescript@3.4.4 (sha512-xt5RsIRCEaf6+j9AyOBgvVuAec0i92rgCaS3S+UVf5Z/vF2Hvtsw08wtUTJqp4djwznoAgjSxeCcU4r+CcDBJA==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.

> npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\vn78009\workspace\newWorkbench\workbench\node_modules.staging\fstream-0aad9635\lib\abstract.js'
>   npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\vn78009\workspace\newWorkbench\workbench\node_modules.staging\fstream-0aad9635\lib\collect.js'`

Answer (score 1):

Remove package-lock.json, Remove node_modules, and then install packages using `npm install'.
This resolved issue for me.

Comment: Please mark answer if this helps you.